# cannot access class org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI (in module java.xml.crypto)

Tags: java, java-17, openjdk-17

we are using  XMLSignatureFactory  to get instance like below. which was working fine in JDK 12 but now when upgrading to JDK17 giving below error in runtime. Any one please can provide input.

```
String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
        try {
            return XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());
```

}.......

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.test.OutboundMessageHandlerImpl cannot access class org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI (in module java.xml.crypto) because module java.xml.crypto does not export org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom to unnamed module @6580cfdd
```

Comment: did you find a workaround for this? I have the same issue when I tried upgrading from java 11 to 17 and couldn't find a solution anywhere... I downgraded the java version for now

Answer (score 1):

Java 17 is stricter with reflections/introspection.

As a quick-fix you can add `--add-opens java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom=ALL-UNNAMED` as vm options when running the application. But you should upgrade the package to a version which is java 17 compatible if possible.

Comment: Didn't work for me to put this as vm option. By upgrading the package to a compatible version what do you mean? Which dependency to upgrade? Thanks